# Скрипт на Python, который перезагрузит браузер, если занятое ОЗУ больше, чем 90% от того, что есть

Tags: python

С перезагрузкой браузера проблем нет, а вот как отследить ОЗУ я не знаю. Я нашёл библиотеку memory_profiler и одна из её функций позволяет узнать сколько памяти занимает скрипт, но мне всё ещё не понятно как узнать сколько всего памяти на устройстве. Может для решения моей проблемы есть какие то более удобные способы?

Comment: А какое устройство, какая операционка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

psutil [virtual_memory](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.virtual_memory) и [memory_info](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.memory_info)

```
import psutil, os

o = psutil.virtual_memory()
print(o)  # os
# svmem(total=17170841600, available=9212215296, percent=46.3, used=7958626304, free=9212215296)

s = psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info()
print(s)  # scr
# pmem(rss=49266688, vms=273924096, num_page_faults=16341, peak_wset=49717248, wset=49266688, peak_paged_pool=361912, paged_pool=361816, peak_nonpaged_pool=35384, nonpaged_pool=35304, pagefile=273924096, peak_pagefile=275312640, private=273924096)
```